# NSTimeInterval set day to zero

Tags: ios, time

I want to use a count down timer (namely MZTimerLabel) and I give a NSTimeInterval object to initialize the count down time.

I want to display the NSTimeInterval as a date, and the classic way is

```
let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(8) // 8 seconds
let dateRef = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:0)
let dateFormattedInterval = dateRef.dateByAddingTimeInterval(timeInterval)
print(dateFormattedInterval)
// it shows 2001-01-01 00:00:08 instead of 0000-00-00 00:00:08
```

Is there a way to display a correct time interval as a formatted date ?

Comment: How is 8 seconds a date?  Do you mean you want to format it as HH:MM:SS?

Comment: A date is a point in time. A time interval is the difference between two points in time. You cannot represent a time interval as a date.

Comment: If you want to display a time interval as days, hours, minutes and seconds, it's just basic integer math using division (`/`) and remainder (`%`)...

Comment: @jcaron You can if one of the dates is an epoch...

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, I want to format the 8 seconds interval as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

Comment: Where does the year/month/day come from?

Comment: How long is a "month" or a "year"?

Comment: The number of days can easily be obtained by dividing the interval by 86400, but months and years are an altogether different matter...

Comment: @trojanfoe if the interval is smaller than a year, I will simply display 0000 as year

Comment: @jcaron, you are right, I did not realize that. I guess I will use your solution (basic divisions)

Comment: You cannot use `NSDateFormatter` for this.  You'll have to code it yourself and it will be a nightmare, given different number of days in a month, and leap years, etc.

Comment: It would need to be relative to a particular existing date. What you're asking for is basically meaningless to a user if the value is that large unless it is relative to now, the current time at which the user observes the value.